# How to write diff() mathematically?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, python, function

I am using R/Python `diff()` operation. e.g., https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html

I would like to know if there is a mathematical function that denotes what `diff` does?

In other words, assume I have a list of N numbers. How can I denote this using a methematical function?

mylist = [x1, x2, x2, ..., xN]

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you want to apply `diff` to a vector $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ of length $n$. The result will be the vector $(d_1, \dots, d_{n-1})$ of length $n-1$ with entries

$$ d_i = x_{i+1}-x_i. $$

---

Some people will use the notation $x_{[i]}$ or similar to indicate the vector $x$ with the $i$th component left out, i.e., $x_{[i]}=(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)$. With this, you can write more concisely in vector form

$$ d = x_{[1]} - x_{[n]}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. Just wondering how to write this function `sd(diff(x))/abs(mean(diff(x)))` mathematically. Currently, I am having it as `σ(diff(x))/|µ(diff(x))|`. Please let me know your thoughts on this. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)

Comment: That sounds useful enough. You can always write down the formulas for the mean and SD in terms of the differences $d_i$. And if you really want, you can substitute in the $x_i$, but it will get progressively less enlightening.

Comment: Interesting notation for leaving out $i$; haven't seen that one before. I have often seen $x_{-i}$ for that

Comment: @StephanKolassa I did not get what you  said. It would be really great if you could show me what you said symbolically. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you once again :)